# How to get current displayed page object during navigation form one page to other?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7

i have made an application where MainPage is the opening window of my application. 
Then i added two pages to the project. One is portrait and other is of landscape mode. 
Now there is a controller class which will be controlling the main working of the application. Now i want that when i navigate from main page to portrait or landscape page then i will able to get the object of the current opening page which i require in controller class.
Is there any work around ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to get the details of the page that was last opened automatically. You will have to do this yourself.

There are 2 common approaches to this:

1. Use a global variable to store that last viewed page.
2. Use a messaging system to inform the MainPage which page was displayed last.

Comment: Just to add to 2. that it's quite common to use "query parameters" on the navigation address to do the message - as the NavigationService will always be able to give you the current url - `CurrentSource`

Comment: @Stuart but that doesn't work for going back, only for going forward.

Comment: @Matt - eh? Why not? I use query params in overflow7 - each page just responds to the checks in OnNavigatedTo() and the bookmark tracker is a singleton object that just checks NavigationService.CurrentSource (got to admit that I don't 100% understand the English in the OP though!)

Comment: @Stuart so if you navigated from page1 to page 2 and pass qry string params you can still see those when you later navigate back to page 1?

Comment: No - of course not - but not sure that's what the OP wants from "current opening page" - guess we'll have to wait and see :)

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience.  "current opening page"- suppose there is a Main Page. I can navigate to page 1 and page 2 from main page according to the condition. Now as i navigate from Main page to page 1 then i want to get the object of page 1 on main page.

Comment: @rubyraj depending on what you want from page1, the simplest way to do this may be to pass the (or a copy of the) object that page1 is bound to back to main page.